# Compile less with different variables

Tags: css, less

I'm trying to compile less into two sites, with the same design but different colors.

My set up is:

```
variables.less // contains ex: @grayBg: #efefef;


base.less
elements.less
breakpoints.less // all 3 starts with @import (reference) "variables";


output.less  // builds css with:
    @import "base"
    @import "elements"
    @import "breakpoints"
```

Now I want to add a `variables_siteB.less` and `output_siteB.less`

I've tried to remove the `@import (reference)` from the files and instead add it into `output.less`, but this results in a compiler error.

We don't use `gulp`, `grunt` etc, instead we compile in `php` using http://robo.li

Thanks

Comment: What is the error? What have you done to try to track down and fix the problem?